# Writing $axy + bx + cy + d$ in the form $a(x-\alpha)(y-\beta)+\gamma$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, completing-the-square

I came across a problem in which we needed to rewrite an equation of the form:
$$axy + bx + cy + d$$
in the form
$$a(x-\alpha)(y-\beta)+\gamma$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are known constants and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are constants to be found.

For example, we can write
$$-4xyx+x+2y+2 \qquad\text{as}\qquad -4(x-0.5)(y-0.25)+2.5$$

I'm trying to generalise this factorisation so that I could do something similar irrespective of what the numbers are.

The form is quite similar to completing the square, and so I was wondering if perhaps this would require a similar approach.

Comment: Not following.  What goes wrong if you just expand the desired form and match coefficients with the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, divide by $a$
to get it in the form
$xy+ux+vy+w
$.

Then,
note that
$(x+v)(y+u)
=xy+ux+vy+uv
$,
so
$xy+ux+vy
=(x+v)(y+u)-uv
$.

This is the kind
of algebraic manipulation
that you need to get
comfortable with.